# Core Data Fetch One to Many Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Problem:

Error of Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'.

I want to fetch all the attributes in Section and News entities. But those attributes should  match with each other. For example, suppose I have a section name = "yy", and its matched news are title="sports" and title="daily news". Another section name="aa", with only one matched news title which is title = "Horoscopes" and so on... Get correct section attribute with its correct news attributes(one or many).

1. Here is the core data structure:

[image]

2. And I have entity classes of news and section: (Auto generation)

   ```
   //News.h:
   @class Section;
   @interface News : NSManagedObject

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * updated;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * synopsis;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pub_date;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * imageId;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Section *sectionRelation;
   @end

   // News.m define those attribute as @dynamic

   // Section.h 
   @class News;
   @interface Section : NSManagedObject

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *newsRelation;
   @end

   @interface Section (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
   - (void)addNewsRelationObject:(News *)value;
   - (void)removeNewsRelationObject:(News *)value;
   - (void)addNewsRelation:(NSSet *)values;
   - (void)removeNewsRelation:(NSSet *)values;

   // section.m still @dynamic
   ```
3. I use NSDictionary to insert values into these entities:

   ```
   -(Section*)insertSectionEntity:(NSDictionary*)values
   {
      Section* sectionObject = [NSEntityDescription     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_NEWS_SECTION inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper  coreDataManager]managedObjectContext]];
      [sectionObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:values];
      // I did not use [section addNewsRelationObject:news]; I used in somewhere else.
      return sectionObject;
    }

    -(News*)insertNewsEntity:(NSDictionary*)values
   {
      News* newsObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_NEWS inManagedObjectContext:[[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]managedObjectContext]];
      [newsObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:values];
      return newsObject;
    }
   ```
4. Here is the way I store both entities into core data:

   ```
   // this array include the NSDictionary values of Section and News entity
   -(void)storeNewsAndSectionEntity:(NSMutableArray*)array
   {
      if(array.count!=0){
         News* news       = NULL;
         Section* section = NULL;

        // break into two different dictionaries and store in core data
        for (NSDictionary* dic in array) {
           // name is the attribute of section
           if([dic valueForKey:@"name"]!=nil){
               section = [self insertSectionEntity:dic];
            }
            else{
               news = [self insertNewsEntity:dic];
               [section addNewsRelationObject:news]; // generate relation
            }
         }
         [[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]saveContext]; // save context
       }
   }
   ```
5. Here is the way I fetch all the entities attributes:

   ```
   -(NSArray*)fetchCoreDataNews:(Section*)section
   {
       if([[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]isEntityExist:@"News"]){

        // fectch news in relation with that specific section
        NSArray* newsArray = [[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]fectchEntityBaseOnPredicate:@"News" withPredicate:@"SUBQUERY(sectionRelation, $x, $x.newsRelation == %@).@count != 0" withObject:section];        
        return newsArray;
       }
       else
        return nil;
    }

   -(NSArray*)fetchCoreDataSection
   {
      if([[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]isEntityExist:@"Section"]){
          NSArray* sectionArray = [[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager]fectchAllAttributesFromEntity:@"Section"];
          return sectionArray;
      }
      else
        return nil;
   }

    // I think this causing the problem:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
    -(NSArray*)fectchEntityBaseOnPredicate:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate: (NSString*)predicateString withObject:(id)ManagedObject
    {

      NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContent = [[CoreDataHelper coreDataManager] managedObjectContext];
      NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
      NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContent];

      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString, ManagedObject];
      [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
      [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
      NSArray* fectechedElements = [managedObjectContent executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]; // SELECT
      return fectechedElements;
     }
   ```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please describe what your problem is and what you are trying to do? In a really short sentence?

Comment: I want to fetch all the attributes in Section entity and News entity. But right now, it gives me error says "to-many key not allowed"

Comment: @Marc Mosby I already edited the problem. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we can easily get the attribute of one to many by using ValueForKey.

```
// get section entity
_sectionArray = [[[CoreDataControl initCoreDataControl]fetchCoreDataSection]mutableCopy];

// call relation name of each section
NSSet *news = [[_sectionArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"newsRelation"];    

// get all related news entities in the parents entity
NSArray* allObjects = [news allObjects];

// then you can call each specific attribute in that entity
[[allObjects objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"title"]; // it will return the attribute.... :)
```